# Simple example dependent variables but under some conditions independent

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, independence

I am looking for an example for two random variables that are dependent and sometimes explain the other one, but not in all cases.
To be clear, I do not want two gaussian variables which are correlated and explain each other. I want it to be such that we can in some cases have information about $X$ from $Y$ while in other cases we have information about $Y$ from $X$ but these cases should be distinct.

I can (so far) only think of examples in which $X$ depends on $Y$ but not the other way around.

For example $X=\pm 1$ with certain probabilities and $Y=X^2$ means we can predict $Y$ from $X$ but not the other way around. Now I am looking for an example that has the properties that
\begin{align*}
Y\vert X\in A&\sim Y \\
Y| X \in B &\nsim Y \\
X|Y \in C &\sim X \\
X|Y \in D &\nsim X
\end{align*}
Where $A,B$ are subsets of the event space of $X$ and $C,D$ subsets of the event space of $Y$.
If this does not exist, would you able to show me why not?

Comment: In your example $Y$ is completely determined by $X$ (so indeed $X$ gives information about $Y$). Further if $P(X=1)=p$ and $P(X=-1)=q$ then two cases must be discerned. If $p+q=1$ then $Y=1$ a.s. so that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. If $p+q<1$ then $Y$ gives information about $X$ (so also the other way around).

Comment: There are no examples in which $X$ depends on $Y$ and not the other way around. Dependency is always mutual.

Comment: Dependency is indeed always mutual. Therefore I am asking for conditional dependence and independence.